# How can I fix 'Graph disconnected' error in Keras when creating a Fast RCNN model?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Getting "Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor" when trying to create Fast RCNN Model

I'm trying to develop a Fast RCNN model, and utilizing some assistance provided from https://github.com/kbardool/Keras-frcnn. I have been able to arrange the architecture of a fast-rcnn. But when I am trying to make these arranged layers into a Model using the Keras.models.Model I get an error stating: "Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_2'), name='input_2', description="created by layer 'input_2'") at layer "block1_conv1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []" The code is shown below and I hope someone can help.

My base architecture was a vgg16 model that was then concatenated to a ROI pooling layer. The class that is used in the code to generate the ROI Pooling layer will be in https://github.com/kbardool/Keras-frcnn/blob/cf9685b515695d15ee7688ef81959db171cc0ee2/keras_frcnn/RoiPoolingConv.py#L94. And my coding was done in a Jupyter Notebook

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense, Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, GlobalMaxPooling2D, TimeDistributed
from keras.utils import layer_utils
from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
from keras import backend as K
def nn_base(input_tensor=None, trainable=False):
    input_shape = (224, 224, 3)
    if input_tensor is None:
        img_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
    else:
        img_input = Input(tensor=input_tensor, shape=input_shape)
    bn_axis=3
    # Block 1
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv1')(img_input)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv2')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block1_pool')(x)

    # Block 2
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block2_conv1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block2_conv2')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block2_pool')(x)

    # Block 3
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv2')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv3')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block3_pool')(x)

    # Block 4
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv2')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv3')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block4_pool')(x)

    # Block 5
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv2')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv3')(x)
    #x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block5_pool')(x)

    return x
base_cnn=nn_base(input_tensor=None,trainable=True)

from Roi_Pooling import RoiPoolingConv
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed,Flatten,Dropout

num_rois=len(train_images)
def classifier(base_layers, input_rois, num_rois, nb_classes = 2, trainable=True):

    # compile times on theano tend to be very high, so we use smaller ROI pooling regions to workaround
    pooling_regions=7
    out_roi_pool = RoiPoolingConv(pooling_regions, num_rois)([base_layers, input_rois])
    out = TimeDistributed(Flatten(name='flatten'))(out_roi_pool)
    out = TimeDistributed(Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc1'))(out)
    out = TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.5))(out)
    out = TimeDistributed(Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc2'))(out)
    out = TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.5))(out)

    out_class = TimeDistributed(Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='zero'), name='dense_class_{}'.format(nb_classes))(out)
    # note: no regression target for bg class
    out_regr = TimeDistributed(Dense(4 * (nb_classes-1), activation='linear', kernel_initializer='zero'), name='dense_regress_{}'.format(nb_classes))(out)

    return [out_class, out_regr]
roi_input = Input(shape=(None, 4))
input_shape_img = (224, 224, 3)
img_input = Input(shape=input_shape_img)
#out_roi_pool = RoiPoolingConv(7, num_rois)([base_cnn, roi_input])
model_classifier=classifier(base_cnn,roi_input,num_rois,2,trainable=True)
model_final=Model([img_input, roi_input], model_classifier)
```

The class used to generate the ROI Pooling Layer is as follows:

```
from keras.layers import Layer, InputSpec
import keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

    
class RoiPoolingConv(Layer):
    '''ROI pooling layer for 2D inputs.
    See Spatial Pyramid Pooling in Deep Convolutional Networks for Visual Recognition,
    K. He, X. Zhang, S. Ren, J. Sun
    # Arguments
        pool_size: int
            Size of pooling region to use. pool_size = 7 will result in a 7x7 region.
        num_rois: number of regions of interest to be used
    # Input shape
        list of two 4D tensors [X_img,X_roi] with shape:
        X_img:
        `(1, channels, rows, cols)` if dim_ordering='th'
        or 4D tensor with shape:
        `(1, rows, cols, channels)` if dim_ordering='tf'.
        X_roi:
        `(1,num_rois,4)` list of rois, with ordering (x,y,w,h)
    # Output shape
        3D tensor with shape:
        `(1, num_rois, channels, pool_size, pool_size)`
    '''
    def __init__(self, pool_size, num_rois, **kwargs):

        self.dim_ordering = K.image_data_format()

        self.pool_size = pool_size
        self.num_rois = num_rois

        super(RoiPoolingConv, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
 
        self.nb_channels = input_shape[0][3]

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        
        return None, self.num_rois, self.pool_size, self.pool_size, self.nb_channels

    def call(self, x, mask=None):

        assert(len(x) == 2)

        img = x[0]
        rois = x[1]

        input_shape = K.shape(img)

        outputs = []

        for roi_idx in range(self.num_rois):

            x = rois[0, roi_idx, 0]
            y = rois[0, roi_idx, 1]
            w = rois[0, roi_idx, 2]
            h = rois[0, roi_idx, 3]
            
            row_length = w / float(self.pool_size)
            col_length = h / float(self.pool_size)

            num_pool_regions = self.pool_size
            x = K.cast(x, 'int32')
            y = K.cast(y, 'int32')
            w = K.cast(w, 'int32')
            h = K.cast(h, 'int32')

            rs = tf.image.resize(img[:, y:y+h, x:x+w, :], (self.pool_size, self.pool_size))
            outputs.append(rs)

        final_output = K.concatenate(outputs, axis=0)
        final_output = K.reshape(final_output, (1, self.num_rois, self.pool_size, self.pool_size, self.nb_channels))
        final_output = K.permute_dimensions(final_output, (0, 1, 2, 3, 4))

        return final_output
    
    
    def get_config(self):
        config = {'pool_size': self.pool_size,
                  'num_rois': self.num_rois}
        base_config = super(RoiPoolingConv, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```